# A is a m x n matrix, what is the formula for the rank in terms of m and Dim Nul(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

My book has asked the following question:

> Let $A$ be an $m×n$ matrix.
>
> Suppose dim Nul(A) = 3
>
> Give a formula for the rank of A in terms of m or n.

Now, I know that the formula is (what I have been taught is):

**rank (A)+ dim Nul(A)= n**

---

But, the question says in terms of **m or n**, and I know only how to express in terms of n, which I have shown above. **This got me thinking, is there an acceptable way of writing up a formula in terms of m?**

Comment: No. Adding all-zero rows to a matrix $A$ increases the value of $m$, but the rank stays the same, and the null space stays the same. Good question, though.

Comment: @CarlHeckman "Adding all-zero rows to a matrix A increases the value of $m$" ? Really? I thought adding rows increases the value of n. Because m stands for the number of columns and not rows.

Comment: $m$ is the number of rows, $n$ is the number of columns. (Maybe not, if you're studying in China ...). $\left(\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\end{matrix}\right)$ is a $2\times3$ matrix, which has 2 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Oh I get it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Adding all-zero rows to a matrix $A$ increases the value of $m$, but the rank stays the same, and the null space stays the same. Good question, though.